# How to solve this system in matlab?

Tags: matlab

$$\begin{align}
    x_1 &= 20000+0.5x_2+0.1x_3 \\
    x_2 &= 40000+0.2x_1+0.6x_3  \\
  x_3 &= 20000+0.1x_1+0.25x_2
\end{align}
$$
I want to write the system as $Ax=b$, what will then $A$, $b$ and $x$ be?
I suppose $x$ should be $[x_1, x_2, x_3]$ but then I must solve for all of the variables?

### Update

Did I formulate the system correctly as $Ax=b$?
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
     -1 &   0.5 &  0.1 \\
        0.2 &  -1 &  0.6 \\
        0.1 & 0.25 &  1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
b=\begin{pmatrix}
-20000 \\-40000 \\-20000
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
and
$$
x=\begin{pmatrix}
x1  \\ x2 \\x3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

### Update 2

I think I got it right, did it this way in matlab:

```
>> A=[-1 0.5 0.1;0.2 -1 0.6;0.1 0.25 -1]

A =

   -1.0000    0.5000    0.1000
    0.2000   -1.0000    0.6000
    0.1000    0.2500   -1.0000

>> b=[-20000 -40000 -20000]'

b =

      -20000
      -40000
      -20000

>> x=A\b

x =

  1.0e+004 *

    6.5248
    8.1135
    4.6809

>>
```

Comment: You will need to form $A$ and $b$ by hand. You can then use $x=A/b$  to solve the linear system $Ax=b$.

Comment: @Daryl Thank you for the comment. I followed your advice so you can inspect my update that I can continue to develop intosomething that I can load into matlab.

Comment: Yes, except $A_{33}$ should be $-1$, not $1$. Then / will do the job for you. For help, at the MATLAB prompt, type help mldivide.

Comment: @Daryl Of course, it should be -1. Now I understand this part and can go on with formulating it in matlab. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I will add this as an answer.]

EDIT: I had the wrong operator. I have updated all operators to `\` which is the correct operator to solve $Ax=b$. The operator `/` solves $A^Tx=b$.

You will need to form $A$ and $b$ by hand. You can then use `x=A\b` to solve the linear system $Ax=b$.

Your matrix $A$ is almost correct. The $(3,3)$ entry should be $-1$, not 1.

For help with the `\` operator, at the MATLAB prompt, type `help mldivide`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I exercised the solution in matlba and updated the question with the numbers I got that I also could verify fit the equations. So it must be right.

Answer (score 1):

sol1 = inv(A)*b;
it's the most simplest question

Comment: @M-AskmanYou definitely want to use the '\' operator for solving standard linear systems.
The use of 'inv()' is rather costly (see example in reference)!
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/inv.html